# Java keytool (keytool) not found, please install it

Tags: java, python, android, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to create an android app using `buildozer`. I have designed the app using `kivy` and it is working with no errors. I have installed `buildozer` alongwith   all the dependencies given in the documentation. But, I am still getting this error of not finding `Java keytool` when I run the command `buildozer android debug`.

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Debian 'dpkg' package management program version 1.19.0.5 (amd64).
This is free software; see the GNU General Public License version 2 or
later for copying conditions. There is NO warranty.
# Search for Git (git)
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython (cython)
#  -> found at /home/trillian/.local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler (javac)
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool (keytool)
# Java keytool (keytool) not found, please install it.
```

I even searched for this file using `locate keytool` and got the following output:

```
/etc/alternatives/keytool
/etc/alternatives/keytool.1.gz
/usr/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/ja_JP.UTF-8/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/keytool
```

I don't know know what is the problem even when the `keytool` is present in the required location.

In addition:
Command `which keytool` gives no output

Command `buildozer -verbose` gives following output:

```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
No default command set.
Use "buildozer setdefault <command args...>"
Use "buildozer help" for a list of all commands"
```

Comment: You need to install a JDK.  Any JDK (Oracle or OpenJDK), any version.  Once you you so, you should find keytool in your install directory, `bin/keytool`.  It sounds like you have keytool ... but buildozer wants it, but isn't finding it.  Q: Do you have $JAVA_HOME defined in the environment you're running buildozer in?  Q: Try running buildozer -verbose`, and copy/paste the relevant snippet (regarding "keytool") into your post.

Comment: That's odd. Can you add the output of `which keytool`?

Comment: Output for `buildozer -verbose`:
```
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
No default command set.
Use "buildozer setdefault <command args...>"
Use "buildozer help" for a list of all commands"
```

Comment: Command `which keytool` gives no output

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- If there was any such output he wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne `which` doesn't "give no output". If the command is not found, it says `which: no keytool in (highly:relevant:PATH)`.